# Многозначная зависимостью в SQL

Tags: sql

Есть такая зависимость R(A,B,C) которая представлена таблицой ниже:
A B C

1. A B C
2. 1 2 3
3. 1 3 2
4. 1 2 2
5. 3 2 1
6. 3 2 3

Вопрос состоит в следующем:
Какие из перечисленных ниже многозначных зависимостей НЕ удовлетворяют R

1. BC ↠ A
2. BC ↠ C
3. C ↠ A
4. A ↠ B ✔

Правильный ответ последний,но почему я так и не пойму.
Обьясните пожалуйста мне кто как сможет
P.S. не нужно скидовать ссылки с википедии я там уже был и ничерта не понял

Answer (score 1):

почитай вот [тут](http://www.intuit.ru/department/database/rdbintro/8/rdbintro_8.html)